# Untar an archive in the directory it is currently at (without noting destination path)

Tags: tar

While in `~/public_html` I ran:

```
tar -zxvf example.com/extensions/MobileFrontend-REL1_32-9b48b3c.tar.gz
```

I assumed the untarred directory (named `MobileFrontend`) would appear under `example.com/extensions` (the directory in which its archive is currently at) but instead it appeared in `~/public_html`.

How to untar an archive in the directory it is currently at (without noting destination path)?

Comment: Some versions of `tar` have a `-C directory` option that changes the directory. You can use this and the `dirname` command to produce `extract(){ local t=$1; shift ; tar -zxvf "$t" -C "$(dirname "$t")" "$@" ; }` but I wouldn't bother unless I was doing it a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to change to that directory or specify it with `-C` . Tar extracts to the current directory by default.

```
cd example.com/extensions ; tar -zxvf ./MobileFrontend-REL1_32-9b48b3c.tar.gz
```

or

```
tar -zxv -C example.com/extensions -f example.com/extensions/MobileFrontend-REL1_32-9b48b3c.tar.gz
```